# $PATH not finding Android command in OSX

Tags: android, macos, cordova, path, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to build a phonegap application, but after installing the Android SDK, I cannot build the app because the `android` command is not found in my $PATH.

**Error:**

**$ phonegap build android:**

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
```

**$ echo $PATH:**

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/build-tools:[/Development/adt-bundle/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609]/bin
```

**My current .bash_profile**

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/build-tools
##
# Your previous /Users/macness/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/macness/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2014-02-12_at_20:16:11
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-02-12_at_20:16:11: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

export ANT_HOME="[/Development/adt-bundle/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609]" 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
```

Comment: what happens when you run `android` in a terminal ?

Comment: @njzk2 `-bash: android: command not found`